# How to refactor out server-specific parameters?

Tags: jenkins, refactoring, jenkins-pipeline

Currently my `Jenkinsfile` looks like following:

```
def git_credentials_id = '6cf44519-d541-458f-9ef2-78cada281dca1'
def git_url = 'git@gitlab.corp.local:Group_name/repository.git'
def evaluation_dataset_path = '/mnt/data/evaluation_dataset/'

pipeline {
    parameters {
            string(
    ...
    }
}
```

Now we plan to collaborate with another team, that uses their own infrastructure (own Jenkins; own repository, even not git, P4; etc).

This makes irrelevant first three lines of the file.
There is also a checkout stage, tied to git, but, I hope that refactoring of checkout command would be similar to refactoring of the credentials.

How can I split this Pipeline code, so that both teams could use its "immutable" part and substitute their own credentials and paths?

What are the best practices here?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer.

Put these values into properties file and read them using utility-steps plugin.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md#configuration-files